# How can we build a UML class diagram for single page vue js component?

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vue-component

I used the UML class diagram for java class but this time, I am developing a web application that uses a single file component.

I am asking how can we get a class diagram for this Vue js component. How about the watch and computed?

```js
var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#demo',
  data: {
    message: "xy",
    firstName: 'Foo',
    lastName: 'Bar',
    fullName: 'Foo Bar'
  },
  watch: {
    firstName: function (val) {
      this.fullName = val + ' ' + this.lastName
    }
  },
   computed: {
    reversedMessage: function () {
      return this.message.split('').reverse().join('')
    }
  },
  methods: {
  reverseMessage: function () {
    return this.message.split('').reverse().join('')
  }
}
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
<p> {{ fullName }}</p>
<p>message: {{ reversedMessage }}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Trying to generate a UML Diagram from my Vue.js app too. 
Did you figure out a way to do this?